# Location manager issue in Android

Tags: android, service, location

I have one problem in location service. I am developing one application that has
the location service that always keep running in background. My location service retrieve
the network provider location on every-one minute.

The problem is when my application is closed. my background service is running but 
some time my location magner object get **NULL** so it stop retrieving location update.

Now to overcome this issue i have make one timer using handler that running for 3 minute and keep checking that my service is running and location object is alive.

But still i am having issue that why android os make null to my location manager object.

Can anyone suggest how i can keep my location manager object alway running.

please don't suggest me to use the alarm manager as i don't want use that code as part
of my application.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The [Android application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) gets created first, and persists for longer than any of the activities associated with an application.  If don't yet have an application object, setting one up and then managing the location updates from your application object instead of an activity might help.  Also, it sounds like you're getting a reference to the LocationManager each time you want to call it.  Instead, get the LocationManager when your application first starts up, and store the reference to it in your application object.  Nothing in Android can then change your own reference and make it NULL.